# error on FileInputStream.java

Tags: java

I Have write the following code and introduce these errors. My codes is:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
/*import com.csvreader.CsvReader;*/ 

public class CsvReaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            String pathName = System.getProperty("user.dir") +  
                    (CsvReaderExample.class.getPackage() == null ? "" : "\\" + 
                    CsvReaderExample.class.getPackage().getName().replace('.', '\\'));
            FileReader klausuar = new 
                    FileReader("klausurphase_propa_anonym.csv");
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader("klausuar");
            String [] nextLine;

            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
                System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + nextLine[2] + 
                     nextLine[3] + nextLine[4]);
            }
        klausuar.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
}
```

---

Stacktrace

```
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at CsvReaderExample.main(CsvReaderExample.java:12)
```

Can anyone help me ?? Thanks in advance.

Khitam

Comment: these errors - What error?

Comment: what is happening at line 12. that is where the problem occours

Comment: Why have you trimmed the stack trace?

Comment: Cleanup your code and you will probably find the error yourself. Also always read the error message. Stack trace is a secondary information to the exception message, which you have left out when writing this question.

Answer (score 0):

While this is kind of a vague guess, since you did not post the actual Exception, I am confident enough to post this an an answer. Maybe it helps.

You define a variable `pathName`, but never use it, so my guess is that the line where you create your `FileReader` was actually meant to be this:

```
FileReader klausuar = new FileReader(pathName + "klausurphase_propa_anonym.csv");
```

Also, since the file seems to be located on your classpath, instead of trying to construct an absolute path from the package, you should instead use [`getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or  [`getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Note that there's a second error: When creating the `CSVReader`, you pass the name of the `klausuar` variable as a string, not the variable itself. Instead, this should be:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(klausuar);
```